# uninitialized constant YourSpace::UsersController::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

error

```
  uninitialized constant YourSpace::UsersController::User
```

controller

```
 class YourSpace::UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
 @title = YourSpace
end

def edit
 @title = YourSpace
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

 def update
  name = params[:user][:name]

  if name.blank?
   flash[:notice] = "Name can not be blank dawg!"
   redirect_to :back
  else
   User.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(params[:user])
   # redirect_to :action 'show'
   redirect_to :action => :show
   # render :action => 'show'
 end
 end

 def index
  @title = YourSpace
  @users = User.limit(100).order('created_at DESC')
 end

 def show
  @title = YourSpace
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


root 'site#home'
get '/about', to: 'site#about', as: :about

namespace :your_space do
 resources :users
end

namespace :word_cloud do
 resources :words, :only => [:index, :create]
end

namespace :word_clock do
 resources :page, :only => [:index]
end

namespace :wish do
 resources :page, :only => [:index]
end

end
```

when firing up the rails server, I get error in the YourSpace UsersController where this line of code @users = User.limit(100).order('created_at DESC') is apparently all jacked up. Please know I'm trying to duplicate 180 websites in 365 days which is mostly built using ruby and rails. I'm following closely along the repo to build muscle memory. very much new to learning how to think, and programming.

Comment: You might want to refactor this code, especially when it comes to `update` action. few issues:

- you first want to find the model if it exists this will raise the error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - which will render 404 page
- you want to render :edit form again, this way the model will have all the values the user has entered.

Comment: no model associated with your_space. it's my understanding models in the mvc framework are only needed when dealing with a relational database, right? therefore, I'm only required to generate a controller with the appropriate views for rendering to the browser. again, still completely new to learning how to think, and setting up a rails application. while I'm finding myself moving through the hartl tutorial, I've decided to diverge and recreate a project by someone in the community where 180 sites were developed in 180 days. again, to build muscle memory.

Comment: Learning through fingers is fine. However, you want to learn the good stuff.

this code looks good https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users

Comment: Models in rails are for interacting with database. it doesn't have to be a relational database (usually MySQL or PostgreSQL) it can be document database (like MongoDB) or anything you want really.

Controllers are basically the application entry point. it can render a html template. it can also render json response, can redirect (those are the big 3's i would say)

Views - representation layer, it can be a html markup. and it can be a json view, when you build an api.

Comment: so much awesomeness to learn about. the app is still broke, so perhaps I need to head back to the hartl tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First thought was wrong.. to solve the problem change `User` to `::User`

---

My first thought is that you need to put this `YourSpace::UsersController` in `app/controllers/your_space/users_controller.rb`. Rails forces directory structure.

Comment: parking lot structure for the controller is set up like this at moment in controllers with your_space directory with a users_controller.rb file, which I think you're saying is set up wrong?

Comment: i kinda feel stupid now. didn't read your question to the fullest. For reasons I am not quite certain of he automatically namespaced the `User` mode to current namespace. If you would write `::User` it will know to go back to root namespace.

Comment: I'm still not understanding

Comment: `User` is your model. By writting `User` you are refering to that class. But if you look at your error he is trying to access `User` namespaced to `YourSpace::UsersController`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: damn, this is going to take forever to learn, just hasn't clicked, yet. thanks for reaching out

Comment: kinda understand, but for obvious reasons, I can't apply it to the project to make it work properly. fml